# Patching Python packages, installed as dependencies with Pip

Tags: python, pip

I have a Python project, which can be installed using Pip. Along with installing the project, Pip downloads and installs some Python packages as dependencies. There's py-amqplib among them. To achieve the desired functionality I need to apply a patch to py-amqplib after its installation. Is there any way to do it automatically in the process of installation of my project?

Comment: Did my suggestions work for you? Or did you run in any further problems?

Comment: @arie your suggestions do not solve the problem.
For example: in a module/package you cannot change the dependencies to a private fork, as no direct deps are allowed in pypi modules.
So your suggestion boils down to: fork, patch, create custom pypi index, publish, depend.
Repeat each time you need a bleeding edge change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could fork the project (there seems to be a [py-amqplib-repo](https://github.com/vukasin/py-amqplib)  on github) and apply your patches.

If your patch [gets integrated upstream](http://help.github.com/pull-requests/), fine.

If not, you can still use pip to install your patched fork directly:
 http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/logic.html

Comment: How to do patch without fork?

Comment: @VityaSchel it seems like you cannot, python is still in stone age with its packaging compared to javascript.